# Is it better to have javascript functions in a file or in html tag?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering, is it better to have javascript functions located in html tags, like for example

```
<form method="post" action="/web/comment" 
onsubmit="jQuery.ajax({
   type:'POST', 
   dataType:'html', 
   data:jQuery(this).serialize(), 
   success:function(data, textStatus) {
        jQuery('#comment').html(data);
   }, 
   url:'/web/comment'
 }); 
 return false;">
```

Or in external files like for example script.js ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you can't fit it into 20-30 chars, don't even consider writing it inline.

Comment: Even if you were to put it in the HTML file itself, it's best *not* to put the JS inline like you did there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider readability (for humans) - in your example the code would surely be more readable in a separate file (as you suggest), or in a `script` block in your html file.

for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitComments(commentsForm) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            dataType:'html', 
            data:jQuery(commentsForm).serialize(), 
            success:function(data, textStatus) { jQuery('#comment').html(data); }, 
            url:'/web/comment'
        });
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="/web/comment" onsubmit="submitComments(this); return false;">
```

Some pointers regarding jQuery

- Rather than directly setting the `onsubmit` property, check out [jQuery's event binding syntax](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). This allows you to nicely encapsulate your event handling code and its plumbing all in one place, which typically makes your code easier for people to understand.
- It is more usual to simply use the shorthand `$` rather than `jQuery` in your code (unless `$` has already been defined as meaning something else).

Comment: I agree, always in an external file unless it has to be in the page for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer, that sounds right to me.
Regarding the shorthand `$` I completely agree, the example I pasted was generated by a symfony's plugin, the purpose was only to show an example ;)

Answer (score 2):

its always better to have all your javascript code in a separate file..

Read [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Here is also a link that I like about this topic: http://wardley.org/computers/web/separation.html

Comment: I would say "usually" rather than "always".

Comment: why usually?? example would be nice.. I dnt see any gains of nt doing it

Answer (score 1):

Putting them in external files makes your markup a lot easier to read and to maintain. It also enables you to reuse scripts across pages without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to have only the form, with its own ID, in the HTML then attach the events like this.

HTML:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" action="/web/comment">
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oForm = document.getElementById("Form1");
    oForm.onsubmit = function() {
        //code here....
        return false;
    }
};
```

As you're already using jQuery, this can be made even more simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#Form1").bind("submit", function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            dataType:'html', 
            data:jQuery(this).serialize(), 
            success:function(data, textStatus) {
                jQuery('#comment').html(data);
            }, 
            url:'/web/comment'
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just a typo it should be `jQuery("#Form1").bind("submit", function() {`

Answer (score 1):

excluded javascript code in a seperate file will enable the browser to cache it ;) benefit: page loads much quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is too small part of code to move it in separate file, it will be better to separate it in script region. Somethink like that (http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
<form method="post" action="/web/comment" id="target">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#target').submit(
jQuery.ajax({
   type:'POST', 
   dataType:'html', 
   data:jQuery(this).serialize(), 
   success:function(data, textStatus) {jQuery('#comment').html(data);}, 
   url:'/web/comment'
 }); 
 return false;
);
</script>
</form>
```